# Unknown proider error with karma jasmine unit tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have a unit test that is created with the Jasmine framework. When I put a single test specification in the describe block I get a pass in the karma console. If I copy that describe block with the test in it ( the it(); ) then I suddenly start getting problems with dependencies that the module uses.

In the console I get errors around unknown providers.

Here is my simple test:

```
 describe('service definition tests', function () {

    it('should be defined', function () {
        expect(sut).toBeDefined();
    });

});
```

and that passes okay. If I copy this block I get an error about dependencies. Which is strange as I've already proved that I can test the 'sut' is defined in the first test.

One thing to note is that I have a beforeEach block that loads the module and provides a dependency and it is this dependency that errors when I've duplicated the test. Here is the beforeEach:

```
 var mockConfig = {};

 beforeEach(function () {
    module('app');
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('myConfig', mockConfig);
    });
});
```

the problem has to be something to do with this beforeEach being as the error I get is about the myConfig dependency.

Here is the error:

```
uncaught Error: [$injecor:unpr] Unknown provider: myConfigProvider <- myConfig <- authorisation
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/unpr?p0=myConfiProvider
```

Comment: I've got a bit further. I created a new js file with the beforeEach block in it. now I can create more tests within the original test file. However if I create another file with tests in I get the dependency error again.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by creating a dummy implementation of myConfig factory so that the test files used this.

```
angular.module('app').factory('myConfig', function() {

    var env = 'test';

    return {
        env: env
    }
});
```

This code lives in a js file that is loaded with the rest of the tests.